# Dual Boot to Single Boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I had installed two operating systems in dual boot mode with a grub menu i.e windows and Ubuntu. Now i have lost the password to Ubuntu OS. If i reinstall windows, grub will not take it and there will be error. I can't see the partition on which Ubuntu was installed. I want to completely remove the Ubuntu and reinstall windows with entire capacity of my Hard Disc available to me with only one OS i.e Windows. Can you help?

Comment: You can reset your password for ubuntu like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Answer (score 0):

If you simply reinstall windows, then the Grub will disappear, and in the beginning when you specify where to install, you can delete the ubuntu partitions.
(ubuntu partitions are not seen in windows, just in partitoning programs)

However, if your problem is, that you lost your password, you can simply enter in grub on "recovery mode", go to "root shell", type

```
passwd <username>
```

and enter the new root password (where  is your username). 
This will be the new password for your user!
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Both can erase your entire Hard Disc and then install the chosen OS.

With the advantage for Ubuntu, that lets you boot from the live DVD or Flash Drive and save your files.